# React js implement CKeditor or Draft

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I want to implement CKeditor or Draft in React.js, how should I go about it, Can some show me that way?

Comment: draft.js is reactjs. Read the source code. It's not trivial to create a rich text editor. https://github.com/facebook/draft-js

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather try ready to use component for that. From what I have checked CKEditor 5 already provides official integration:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html

For CKEditor 4 which is Latest Stable release at the time of writing, there are thrid-party integrations like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ckeditor-component but from what I have heard, the CKE4 team is currently working on [official integration for React](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2480) and Angular so they should be ready soon (I'm guessing within 2-3 months).